# update api not working in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, postman

I have a simple update api which is not working properly. I tested the API in postman by sending only the key and data that needs to be updated but my frontend is sending whole formdata along with the data that are updated. It is working in my postman when I send only the key and the data that needs to be updated but when I send all the data with certain fields as empty string `("")`, it does not get updated.

My models:

```
class Lead(models.Model):    

    title = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=TITLES, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="nepal")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
    /........other fields................................/
```

My views:

```
class LeadsView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]    

    def put(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        print("iam put")
        id = pk
        abc = Lead.objects.get(id=id)
        serializer = LeadSerializer(abc,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                "message": " Leads has been updated",
                "data": serializer.data
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My serializers:

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email= serializers.EmailField(required=False)
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    address = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    company_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    /.................same in other fields............../
    

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        

        fields = ['id','title','first_name','last_name','address','company_name',
                  'city','state','country','phone','source','mobile',
                  'email','gender','date_created','lead_status']
```

Here in serializer level I have put all the fields as required = false but in model level only three fields first_name, last_name and phone are required, other fields can be blank.

When all the fields are present,it gets updated, when some fields are blank as empty string, it doesnt get updated. Also, when only one key+data is sent, it gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

It because your serializer not valid when validate the request data. In this line:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    pass
```

change to:

```
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    pass
```

You will get raise validation error, details about request data.

Comment: Then there is no use of putting every field as required=false in the serializer class. Please suggest. @Mahrus